# Mock global function call while importing

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock, python-unittest.mock

Suppose I have a file called `a.py` with code like

```
import mod1
mod1.a()

def b():
   print("hi")
```

Now if I want to mock fun `b()` then `unittest.py` while have import statement at top like

`from a import b`

at time of import `mod1.a()` will be called. How can I mock that call which is happening at the time of import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider removing code from module top-level, by moving it to a block protected by

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mod1.a()
    ... # the rest of your top level code
```

This way the protected code does not get executed on imports, only when run directly.

If you still need the call there and want to mock it, it is very simple.
With files like this,

```
# mod.py

import mod1
mod1.a()

def b():
   print("hi")


# mod1.py

def a():
    print('Running a!')

# test_1.py
# Note: do not call unittest.py to a file.
# That is the name of a module from the Python stdlib,
# you actually need to use it and things will not work,
# because Python tries to load your file not the library you need.

from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('mod1.a') as mock_a:
    ... # configure mock_a here if there is a need, for example
        # to set a fake a call result
    import mod
    ... # the rest of your testing code. Use `mock_a` if you want to
        # inspect `a` calls.
```

Outside the with `mod1.a` is no longer mocked.
There are other ways to start and stop mocking, you should look into the documentation. Before studying mock make sure you understand well how unittests work and how you can organize your tests.

Comment: I understand but I want that function call to happen on import.

Comment: I am pretty sure that when executing the `patch('mod1.a')`, the module will be loaded to check that it contains what you want to patch, which will trigger the not mocked call before patching it.

Comment: @DanibISHOP is correct. As a test, replace the contents of the `a` method with a `raise` statement instead, and you will see that the exception will always be called and you cannot avoid it. While you will ***evantually*** mock it this way, you are still actually executing that code for real when it ***looks*** for that module.