# Handle Dynamic function call during pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, monkeypatching

---

When `main.py` is executed, the Python interpreter scans all files and executes any functions that were called at the beginning.

In `source/settings.py`, there's a function called `get_settings()`: which act as global variable with function call.

```py
def get_settings():
   # Retrieves settings for production environment
   return {}  # some_dict
    
settings = get_settings()
```

This function is intended to run in production or other environments.

However, when pytest starts, I want to replace the execution of `get_settings()` with a different function located in `tests/conftest.py`:

```py
def get_local_settings():
    # Retrieves settings from the development database
    return {}  # some_dict

with patch('source.settings.get_settings') as mock_settings:
    mock_settings.return_value = get_local_settings()
```

I thought that conftest.py will be called in beginning of test and with mock_settings.return_value will be assigned. So, whenever get_settings() is called get_local_settings() value will be returned.
Despite implementing this logic, `get_settings()` continues to be called when pytest starts.

I'm seeking a solution that doesn't involve modifying `source/settings.py` with conditional logic like:

```py
if ENV == LOCAL:
    settings = tests.conftest.get_local_settings()
else:
    settings = get_settings()
```

---

Comment: I commented on a solution just now to help illustrate being cautious with what is really going on behind the scenes. You will pretty much always be executing that code in the global scope, and should be cautious. I've commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394471/mock-global-function-call-while-importing#comment137502161_59394946). Ultimately, try replacing your `get_settings` code wiith a `raise`, and you will most likely face issues. It might be best to consider updating that `settings` code to be better contained.